# How does a camera flash get high voltage and current from a small battery?

Tags: batteries, coil, solenoid

I am a beginner trying to make coilgun.  I see videos use camera flash circuit with capacitor that outputs 220V and a good current (5A) from 1.5V AAA battery

How does this circuit work to give this power from just 1.5V?

Comment: Why do so many beginners want to make circuits that can kill them?

Comment: I am beginner in building coilgun and solenoid coil, not circuits

Comment: Are you try to move a  mosquito version?

Answer (score 3):

Strobe flashes work by using an oscillator and step-up transformer to charge a capacitor to several hundred volts, and then suddenly passing some of that charge through a second high voltage step-up transformer to get thousands of volts to trigger the strobe tube.

In many of them you can hear the oscillator whining as it charges the capacitor, it takes a number of seconds to get enough charge into the capacitor. At this point the strobe tube will have several hundred volts across it but needs a very high voltage trigger to fire. When the camera shutter is activated the strobe circuit will dump some of the capacitor's charge through a transformer that creates a high voltage pulse on the strobe tube's trigger connection causing the gas in the tube to ionize and conduct the capacitor's charge, creating the flash.

It can use a small battery because it steps low voltage/high current up to high voltage/low current, and then applies that low current to the capacitor over time to build up the charge slowly.